# How to properly debug failures with do-release-upgrade?

Tags: apt, 18.04, upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I'm trying to run `do-release-upgrade` on a system image (when chrooted) and the command fails without any further error messages or guidance:

```
root@gilneas:/var/run# do-release-upgrade 
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [819 B]                                                                                                    
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,240 kB]                                                                                                           
Fetched 1,241 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                                          
authenticate 'bionic.tar.gz' against 'bionic.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'bionic.tar.gz'

Reading cache

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Hit http://mirrors.cc.if.ufrj.br/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                                
Hit http://mirrors.cc.if.ufrj.br/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease                                                                        
Hit http://mirrors.cc.if.ufrj.br/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease                                                                       
Hit http://mirrors.cc.if.ufrj.br/cc/deb xenial InRelease                                                                                
Get:1 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease [3,182 B]                                                             
Get:2 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable/main amd64 Packages [130 kB]                                                    
Hit https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                                                                              
Fetched 133 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                                            
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done

Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
```

It just aborts after the "Reading state information", on the log file `/var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log` theres nothing either:

```
root@gilneas:/var/run# cat /var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log 
2019-07-30 14:08:23,858 INFO Using config files '['./DistUpgrade.cfg.xenial']'
2019-07-30 14:08:23,858 INFO uname information: 'Linux gilneas 4.15.0-55-generic #60-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 2 18:22:20 UTC 2019 x86_64'
2019-07-30 14:08:24,307 INFO apt version: '1.2.32'
2019-07-30 14:08:24,308 INFO python version: '3.5.2 (default, Nov 12 2018, 13:43:14) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]'
2019-07-30 14:08:24,312 INFO release-upgrader version '18.04.34' started
2019-07-30 14:08:24,331 INFO locale: 'en_US' 'UTF-8'
2019-07-30 14:08:24,422 INFO screen could not be run
2019-07-30 14:08:24,463 WARNING estimate_kernel_initrd_size_in_boot() returned '0' for kernel?
2019-07-30 14:08:24,463 WARNING estimate_kernel_initrd_size_in_boot() returned '0' for initrd?
2019-07-30 14:08:24,641 DEBUG Using 'DistUpgradeViewText' view
2019-07-30 14:08:24,728 DEBUG enable dpkg --force-overwrite
2019-07-30 14:08:24,774 DEBUG creating statefile: '/var/log/dist-upgrade/apt-clone_system_state.tar.gz'
2019-07-30 14:08:30,723 DEBUG lsb-release: 'xenial'
2019-07-30 14:08:30,725 DEBUG _pythonSymlinkCheck run
2019-07-30 14:08:30,727 DEBUG openCache()
2019-07-30 14:08:30,728 DEBUG No such plugin directory: ./plugins
2019-07-30 14:08:30,728 DEBUG plugins for condition 'PreCacheOpen' are '[]'
2019-07-30 14:08:30,728 DEBUG plugins for condition 'bionicPreCacheOpen' are '[]'
2019-07-30 14:08:30,728 DEBUG plugins for condition 'from_xenialPreCacheOpen' are '[]'
2019-07-30 14:08:30,728 DEBUG quirks: running PreCacheOpen
2019-07-30 14:08:30,728 DEBUG running Quirks.PreCacheOpen
2019-07-30 14:08:31,451 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 58297
2019-07-30 14:08:31,452 DEBUG need_server_mode(): run in 'desktop' mode, (because of pkg 'ubuntu-desktop')
2019-07-30 14:08:31,452 DEBUG checkViewDepends()
2019-07-30 14:08:31,453 DEBUG running doUpdate() (showErrors=False)
2019-07-30 14:08:37,647 DEBUG openCache()
2019-07-30 14:08:38,440 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 58297
2019-07-30 14:08:38,441 DEBUG doPostInitialUpdate
2019-07-30 14:08:38,441 DEBUG plugins for condition 'PostInitialUpdate' are '[]'
2019-07-30 14:08:38,441 DEBUG plugins for condition 'bionicPostInitialUpdate' are '[]'
2019-07-30 14:08:38,441 DEBUG plugins for condition 'from_xenialPostInitialUpdate' are '[]'
2019-07-30 14:08:38,441 DEBUG quirks: running bionicPostInitialUpdate
2019-07-30 14:08:38,441 DEBUG running Quirks.bionicPostInitialUpdate
2019-07-30 14:08:43,463 DEBUG abort called
2019-07-30 14:08:43,464 DEBUG openCache()
2019-07-30 14:08:44,245 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 58297
```

The curious thing is that I have two servers with the same issue. One of the servers was running 14.04 and I successfully updated to 16.04 with `do-release-upgrade`, but 16.04 to 18.04 is just a miss.

Just to be extremely clear, the system is running LTSP and the chroot image is the LTSP Fat Client image. And what I'm trying to achieve is updating the images, since the system is already updated.

For the images, creating from the beginning with 18.04 is possible, and I know this, I just want to avoid the mess of remembering all the custom things and just try to upgrade the image. It worked when doing from 14.04 to 16.04; so this should be an issue with 16.04 to 18.04.